# How to find windows disabled and locked accounts in active directory in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, active-directory

I am working on a C++ project and wanted to find a way to find disabled/locked accounts in the Active Directory. I have found below C++
APIs but not sure whether they would solve my purpose or is their some other APIs--

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserenum

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusergetinfo

Also, for reasons outside my control, I have to use  C++ only and not other things like powershell script etc

Comment: yes, you can use this api and check for [`UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/ns-lmaccess-user_info_1) and `UF_LOCKOUT` flags

Answer (score 2):

There are C++ examples of how to do this here: [Searching with the IDirectorySearch Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/searching-with-idirectorysearch)

When you get to the step where you call `ExecuteSearch`, the LDAP query you want to use would be:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(lockoutTime>=1)))
```

That query looks for only user accounts where either:

- The second bit of the [`userAccountControl`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/305144/how-to-use-useraccountcontrol-to-manipulate-user-account-properties) attribute is set, meaning it's disabled, (that weird number is the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_BIT_AND` operator as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax#operators), which is just a bitwise AND), or
- The [`lockoutTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-lockouttime) attribute is 1 or more, meaning it's locked.