# How to find status of all accounts in Active Directory including locked/disabled accounts

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I am working on a windows C++ project. I am currently using windows IDirectorySearch Interface and ExecuteSearch API to get info about all the user accounts in a particular AD. I am using the following filter to pass to  ExecuteSearch API--

```
(&(|(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user))(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)))(cn=*))
```

Now I want to enhance the filter to get information about locked/disabled accounts as well. How can I modify my above filter to achieve this purpose?

Comment: you need `NetQueryDisplayInformation`

Comment: @user496934 did you try this reply? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62832460/how-to-find-windows-disabled-and-locked-accounts-in-active-directory-in-c